# Resizing image and saving it to the specified directory path in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsimage

Using this code I am trying to resize the selected image and then want to save it to a specific path:

```
-(void)processImage:(NSString*)inputPath:(int)imageWidth:(int)imageHeight:(NSString*)outputPath {

    NSImage * img = [NSImage imageNamed:inputPath];
    [img setSize: NSMakeSize(imageWidth,imageHeight)];

}

-(void)startProcessingImages {

    int i; // Loop counter.

    // Loop through all the files and process them.
    for( i = 0; i < [files count]; i++ )
    {
        inputFilePath = [[files objectAtIndex:i] retain];
        NSLog(@"filename::: %@", inputFilePath);

        // Do something with the filename.

        [selectedFile setStringValue:inputFilePath];

        NSLog(@"selectedFile:::: %@", selectedFile);
    }

    NSLog(@"curdir:::::%@", inputFilePath);

    NSString *aString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", thumbnailDirPath , @"/" , fileNameNumber] retain];

    fileNameJPG = [[aString stringByAppendingString:@".jpg"] retain];

    [self processImage:inputFilePath: 66  :55  :thumbnailDirPath];
    [self processImage:inputFilePath: 800 :600 :thumbnailDirPath];
    [self processImage:inputFilePath: 320 :240 :thumbnailDirPath];

}
```

My issue is I am not getting that how to save it to thumbnailDirPath.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should do export your image into file.
currently I only see how to store the TIFF image.

```
[[img TIFFRepresentation] writeToFile:outputPathName atomacally:NO];
```

Where `outputPathName` is the path with file name for your thumbnail file.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8] forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];    
NSData *tiffData = [img TIFFRepresentation];
NSData *JPEGData = [[NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:tiffData] representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:options];
NSError *anError;
if (![JPEGData outputPath options:0 error:&anError])
                MyLog(@"Error saving image: %@ to: %@", anError, outputPath);
```

Check the documentation for [NSJPEGFileType](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/nsbitmapimagerep_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSTIFFFileType) as it will show you the other foramt options for saving, such as PNG.